# How to fix Edge showing empty PDFs?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, microsoft-edge

There is a rare bug reported by some users on the Net that affected also one of my machines with Windows 10 1709 (and 1803 now) recently: all of a sudden Microsoft Edge browser opens *some* PDF files "empty", as white sheets. Here is an example screenshot:

Example (pic): [Edge showing an empty PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhDZS.jpg)

(PDF link: https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1595/en_US/ipad_user_guide.pdf):

This bug does not happen for all PDF files from the Net but just with some.
Can someone help me reset Edge's PDF view feature manipulating/restoring a  probably corrupt Registry?
I already tried to:

1. *Reset* Edge settings and delete everything (cookies etc.)
2. *Repair* Edge from installed Apps panel
3. `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}` from PowerShell
4. Windows 10 *In-place Upgrade*, but didn't fix it
5. Microsoft remote help-desk didn't find a fix

Nothing worked. And no one seems to know which are the Registry keys related to PDF view in Edge, and how to reset them.

P.S.
I don't have Acrobat Reader or 3rd party viewers installed potentially hi-jacking PDF opening.

Comment: Since this is a bug in Edge, I think the best solution is to just use another PDF reader and wait for MS to release a patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I’VE FINALLY FOUND THE CAUSE AND HOW TO SOLVE THE ISSUE!**

This problem happens after you change screen color calibration, when setting a new custom calibration as default for your monitor! From that moment on, some PDFs loaded by Edge will be blank!

How to solve the issue:

- run colorcpl.exe
- enter *Advanced* tab, and then click button *Change system defaults* (at
  bottom). This will open again the same window but in admin mode, to
  change default settings
- enter *Advanced* tab (remember you are in admin mode changing defaults
  this time)
- set as *Device profile*: sRGB IEC61966-2.1 (**IMPORTANT!**)
- set as *Viewing conditions profile*: WCS profile for sRGB viewing
  conditions (**IMPORTANT!**)

close everything, and close also all Edge windows if already running… et voilà!
Edge will be finally able to display all PDFs again!

Comment: Those two settings were already present in my colorcpl.exe.  Edge still renders many pdfs as pure white :-(

Comment: @Camille It changes if you modify them as user or as admin. Follow the Guide carefully and change those settings exactly as indicated. Anyway I assume that the new Edge (Chromium) should have no issues with PDFs anymore.